# Git pull without arguments?

Tags: git, version-control

```
git pull origin foo
```

It will fetch and merge ONLY branch foo. But what happens when you run

```
git pull
```

without any arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git pull` without any arguments defaults to currently checked out branch and the remote repository it is set to track.

[The manual page for git pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) isn't super user friendly but:

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch.
>
> Default values for `<repository>` and `<branch>` are read from the "remote" and "merge" configuration for the current branch as set by `git branch --track`.

Comment: So it wont pull all branches? A lot of people say it pulls all the branches not just the checked out branch. For an example see Jay's answer.

Comment: It might fetch the changes in other branches to a local cache (I'm not sure), but it won't merge them into the other local branches.

Comment: Can i assume it is the same way with git pull?

Comment: My comment is about `git pull`. In my experience, it `git fetch`es new changes for current branch, then merges them into current branch only. I've never had it just `git pull` merge changes on branches other than the currently checked-out one.

Comment: "The manual page for git isn't super user friendly" FTFY :)

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` actually is a `git fetch` then calls `git merge` to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch.

Here is the syntax for the pull:

```
'git pull' [options] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

everything in the `[]` are optional so it should attempt to merge all branches

Answer (score 0):

In my experience `git pull` also includes a `git remote update origin`